# Show a table from data submitted by a form from a user

Tags: plugins, database, table

I would like to show a table on my wordpress site, which is filled by registered users. 
How can I realize this?

So my thoughts are:

- Registered users should be able to submit 2 variables through a
  contact form (1 should be a category, and 2 some text)
- The variables will be pushed to a database so that there is 1 table for every category which is holding the different texts, accompanied
  with the username who submitted it.
- Now there is a table on my wordpress site which gets the data and shows it like this:

Category 1: Text username;
        Text2 username2
        ...

Category 2: Text username;
        Text2 username2
        ...
    and so on

What would you suggest? Is there something like a plugin to realize this easily?

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin : [Contact Form DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/)

Link to download above

Comment: Answers should be more than plain links. Also, recommending plugins as solution is not encouraged and counts as poor quality answers. Please post a real solution

Comment: Looks interesting though. Thanks anyway